# Passthrough is not supported, GL is disabled, ANGLE is

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, webgl

I have following setting in the C# code to use Chrome WebDriver:

```cs
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddUserProfilePreference("plugins.always_open_pdf_externally", true);
options.AddArguments("--test-type", "--ignore-certificate-errors");
options.AddArgument("-no-sandbox");
options.AcceptInsecureCertificates = true;
driver = new ChromeDriver(ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService(), options, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(3));
driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
driver.Url = link_URL;
```

This used to work fine until Chrome is updated from version 90 to 94. With the new updates to the Chrome version, the driver gets hang and shows the following message:
**Passthrough is not supported, GL is disabled, ANGLE is**

I googled for a resolution and found that Setting WebGL to enable mode could resolve this, I was able to make this change in the Chrome settings. But when a new instance of Chrome is launched by WebDriver then WEBGL settings are coming up as disabled only. I have tried to set them via the below code as well:

```cs
options.AddArgument("--enable-webgl-developer-extensions");
options.AddArgument("--enable-webgl-draft-extensions");
```

But the WebGL is still showing up as disabled in the WebDriver's chrome instance.

Could anyone please suggest a resolution of this?

Comment: It may be worth trying this flag: `--ignore-gpu-blocklist`

Comment: It dint resolve the problem. Still getting hang after checking few URLs.

Comment: @LJᛃ Is --ignore-gpu-blocklist a command to enter in CMD or code to put in Selenium file? If the latter, where in the file would I put this?

Comment: You'd pass it as an argument for chrome, i.e. using the `ChromeOptions` object like OP.

Comment: I have the same issue, it was working in my local VM not in production VM. Do we have a solution for this. I have tried `--ignore-gpu-blocklist` but not worked for me